# Problems with loading a BitmapPalette from image file

Tags: c#

I want to load a palette from a bitmap file I have created. The file is 256 px wide and 1 px high.

I use

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();           
image.UriSource = new Uri("image.bmp", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
image.EndInit();

myPalette = new BitmapPalette(image, 256);
```

The strange thing is, that the `Count` property of `myPalette.Colors` is only 244!

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code - BitmapPalette returns **up to** the number of colors specified. From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmappalette.aspx

> Initializes a new instance of the BitmapPalette class based on the
>   specified BitmapSource. The new BitmapPalette is limited to a
>   specified maximum color count.

I created a test bitmap with the same dimensions and a single color, and `myPalette.Colors.Count` returned 1.

Note however that you may actually want to use `Bitmap` from `System.Drawing`, much simpler and this returns the full palette list (256) even if they are all the same:

```
var test = new Bitmap("image.bmp");    
Console.WriteLine(test.Palette.Entries.Length);
```

With the same test as above, that returns 256 entries